# UIAlertView raised from background

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I'm developing an Alarm App.

When the alarm starts sounding I pop up an UIAlertView in order to offer the user the option to stop it. But when the app is in background the UIAlertView doesn't appears.

How can I do a UIAlert similar to the alert that uses the iOS Alarm?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could start reading about this: [Apple documentation about notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). You are probably most likely interested in local notification.